# Internationalization of API Error Messages

Tags: ios, networking, localization, backend

I'm building an iOS app with a custom backend and we want to localize our app for different languages. However, I was wondering if it's considered best practice to translate messages on the iOS side based on the status code and with all the other translations (buttons, labels, etc) or translate error messages on backend when the error message is being generated.

Here's a basic structure of our error format:

```
{
     "statusCode": 402,
     "message": "Error message."
}
```

Some possible advantages of each that were thought of include:

**Backend:**

- Automatically update error messages without needing a front end
  update.
- If the error messages are being generated on backend anyways, why not just translate it there too?

**Frontend**

- Adheres to the recommendation to do all localization as close to the client as possible.
- Keep all the translation tasks on one frontend only instead of having translations on backend and frontend.

What are the best practices/common techniques to internationalize error messages from an API? Is it best to translate them on iOS or backend?

Comment: I don't see an actual question (which should be denoted with a question mark "?"). As it stands, your question is an announcement of what you want to do.

Comment: @RonMaupin Just updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to keep all your localized strings as part of the iOS app, so the server side can keep sending the same message and you do the translation from app side.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation for my app. In my case I retrieve all message from backend for all languages.

Eg :

```
{
     "statusCode": 402,
     "message_en": "Error message.",
     "message_ar": "Error message in arabic."
}
```

Comment: If you have 50 languages this will be very expensive. Better to send the locale to backend and only return the message in the language needed

Comment: @E.Sun Yeah.. thats a good idea

Answer (score 1):

It's best to translate on iOS. Use localization to do that. You have to provide a localized string of every message you want to display.